# How can i get the data from Firestore without streambuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set card with a value from firestore, how can i get that without streambuilder?

```
class _CardsSectionState extends State<CardsSectionAlignment>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int cardsCounter;
  int card = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute a query in initState method of _CardsSectionState and then assign the card value from query result to your integer variable card.

Replace collectionName with your collection name where you have the card value.Replace 'card_value' with name of the field in your collection where card value is.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName').getDocuments().then((val){
          if(val.documents.length > 0){
            card = val.documents[0].data["card_value"];
          }
          else{
            print("Not Found");
          }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to set a value to the `card`, then you need to use either the `snapshot()` method that will return a `Stream` and keep listening for updates or you need to use `get()` that will return a `Future`. In both cases the operation is going to be asynchronous. Therefore there is no way to set it without using `streambuilder`